# Density transformation, distribution function

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory

Suppose $X$ is a real-valued random variable with density $p_X$, so

$$P(X\leq x) = \int_{-\infty}^x \, p_X(y) \, dy.$$ What conditions on a function $f$ are needed (typically?) to find the density of $f(X)$ via $p_X$?

For example: if $f(X) = X^2$, then how do I find the density $p_{X^2}$ of $X^2$?

References appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(\cdot)$ needs to be a *measurable* function with respect to the probability measure so that $f(X)$ is a properly-defined random variable.  For your specific
question, for any $v \geq 0$,

$$P\{X^2 \leq v\} = P\{-\sqrt{v} \leq X \leq \sqrt{v}\} = \int_{-\sqrt{v}}^{\sqrt{v}} p_X(y)\,\mathrm dy$$
from which you can deduce the density of $X^2$.

Comment: thanks. what if $f$ is a polynomial function in $X$, e.g. $f(X) = X^3 + X^2 + X$?

Comment: Then you have to work harder, and you will typically find that depending on the value of $v$, you will get different integral expressions for $P\{f(X) \leq v\}$. Actually, you have already "seen" this since $P\{X^2 \leq v\}$ in the answer above equals $0$ when $v < 0$.